# While working on making holes with "Boolean" two recesses were just cut out (seethrough)instead of keeping the form... How can I fix it?

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

While working on making holes with "Boolean" two recesses were just cut out (seethrough) instead of keeping the form of the cylinder in the hole.
As you can see in the pictures all the other holes kept the form of the cylinder. I need the form for this piece and I haven't found a solution because I can't undo the things I did after I saved the project.
I'd really appreciate any help as soon as possible!
Thank you in advance:)

[image: Screenshot of Problem]
[image: Screenshot of Problem]

Comment: Sometimes setting the _Solver_ to _Fast_ instead of _Exact_ can give a better result. If not we would probably have to inspect the file itself what the problem with the object is.

Comment: Thank you I'll keep that in mind for the future! However, that won't help to undo the two holes that are wrong... Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Select the face in the center, extrude it downwards, then scale the bottom to 0 on the Z axis - if it is connected to the rest of the mesh. If not, select all and press M > Merge > By Distance. Then select the center face, extrude and scale.

Comment: Can you explain that further please? I'm not quite sure how exactly I have to do that...

Comment: And I have no idea how your mesh exactly is in those areas, so I could only guess as well. Which part did you not understand? Selecting the a face? Extruding? Scaling? Is there a face in the center of the holes? Is it part of the original mesh? Have you applied the modifier?

Comment: There is no face in these two holes which I can select an so I'm confused on how to do it.  Isn't there a way where I can put the cylinder into the hole and somehow combine them or something?

Comment: Okay, so there are just holes. If you do not want to or cannot redo it with the _Boolean_ modifier because it is already applied, the easiest way would be to select the vertices on the border of a hole, press F to create a face, press E and Z to extrude on the Z axis downwards, and after extruding press S, Z, 0 to scale the bottom face flat. Combining the holes with cylinders is much more of a fuss.